# 20 most viewed questions that need answers (Updated 5 Apr 2024)

Tags: discussion, editing, unanswered-questions

Some of these questions do have answers, but these answers have negative votes. Only questions with upvotes will be removed from the list. In addition, this list has new questions sprinkled throughout! That means other questions have become popular and need attention, please take a look at the list and answer what you see fit.

**How you can help:**

1. Answer some of these questions!
2. Edit questions to make them more polished.
3. Start a bounty on some of the more interesting questions.
4. Support askers and answerers with upvotes where deserved. If you take a look at [the edits made to this question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3458/revisions), you can find questions that have been answered by the lovely members of the community.

I modified a query to fit Chem.SE to give us unanswered questions (that are open) and have a high number of views. You can also run the query for one or two answers if you want.

I did find that some questions were quite popular and disappointingly did not contain any answers.

If anyone would like to handle some of these questions, that would be amazing!

**Please edit these questions as you see fit (and fix any weird tags.) There is a lot of re-titling to be done and much-needed language cleanup or clarity in the body of the questions. Please upvote the good ones and downvote the bad ones into oblivion.**

[Here is the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/edit/595793).

Below are the Top 20 questions that need answers. Why twenty? I feel that more variety in the questions shown here increases their chance of getting answers.

**Hit the 'ole star button on this meta post to get notified of updates.**

Here are the top 20 questions needing answers:

1. [Why does the reaction of sodium nitrate, aluminium, and sodium hydroxide yield ammonia?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51666)
2. [How to determine the iron content in spinach from a titration with permanganate solution?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42866)
3. [NO coordination linear vs bent - valence electron](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24372)
4. [What exactly is going on in this reaction: sodium bicarbonate (supersaturated aqueous), isopropyl alcohol, and acetic acid (vinegar)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68498)
5. [What happens when isopropyl alcohol expires?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/138407)
6. [Isopropyl Alcohol Vs Acetone for Dissolving Organic Contaminants on PCB](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/134534)
7. [Storing alcohol in a thermos bottle](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86899)
8. [Acid-base reaction: Al(OH)₃ + NaOH](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/76384)
9. [Why do stronger intermolecular forces lead to a larger change in temperature?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/103693)
10. [P2NP synthesis ammonium acetate catalyst?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/99120)
11. [CAS id to SMILES](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/134975)
12. [Calculating the pH of a solution of sodium carbonate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/95818)
13. [Reduction of nitrobenzene in alkaline medium](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/131657)
14. [How to calculate theoretical yield if there are minor products?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/46646)
15. [Calculating distance between adjacent planes (hkl) in a simple cubic crystal](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/118310)
16. [What is the peak at 3200 cm⁻¹ in the IR spectrum of Benzocaine?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/105174)
17. [Unpaired electrons from magnetic moment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/83813)
18. [Intermolecular Forces in Teflon vs Polyethylene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50416)
19. [Electrophilic substitution of an indole as opposed to benzofuran and benzothiophene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/91033)
20. [Nucleophilic Substitution rate comparison 1-bromobutane and 2-bromo-2-methylpropane with NaOH](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/88156)

I will update the above list...

... periodically.

[image: dog joke]

Please comment on any objections to the posted questions and I'll find another to replace them.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM Thanks, I tagged the commenters in each case asking if they would create an answer.