# Lo and behold, the return of editing galore

Tags: discussion

There has been a huge spurt in the number of edits on questions and answers, as most of you would have noticed.

I am not against editing; I actually appreciate many of the edits, including the ones on my posts. They really were worthwile and made much sense to me.

Please note I am not posting this on meta to point fingers, grill, roast, bake or fry anyone here: I just feel we need to sit down (if not already) and discuss/realize that editing has reached a new maximum, especially on very old posts, and correct ourselves if necessary.

I wish to highlight that they are being bumped to the home page, and really cloud up the place. Our community isn't that small and is having a steady inflow of new users and new questions everyday.

None of the above matters, but this does: **I really was quite disappointed at the trivial nature of several edits** (refer to links at the end and in comments) and the **incompleteness of some others.**

The SE system is very transparent, and I have been studying this for quite some time now.

Editing is encouraged: please help our site edge towards perfection. But I hope you might offer some insightful discussion with regards to the present situation, and exercise discretion and restraint when necessary.

**Some examples for the sake of reference:**
Unnecessary edit: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/73089/revisions
Incomplete+Unnecessary edit(image description is vital): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/115071/revisions

Please take it positively, we all care about the site.

---

Some have highlighted that the user was purposely bumping posts to the homepage. In that case the edit summary must have mentioned that, **provided the bump was necessary.** In most cases it wasn't.

Comment: Related: [Prevention of unnecessary edits of old posts.](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3732/prevention-of-unnecessary-edits-of-old-posts); [Editing gone wild](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/editing-gone-wild).

Comment: Having a couple of examples might actually be helpful in this situation.  I think we can all be objective about it.

Comment: @jonsca Here are two: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/115541/revisions and  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/114716/revisions (revison 4 in both)

Comment: @jonsca I am in no wise condemning a single user.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/47346/revisions and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/115071/revisions and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/73089/revisions too

Comment: @andselisk Point to be noted: What I find disturbing is if these edits were made by a <2K user (which will need approval), all these edits would be straight-out **rejected**. And it's not about the +2 rep.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer I agree that the examples you have shown seem to be too superficial of edits. A lot of these examples come from the recently popular meta question https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/20-unanswered-questions-with-many-upvotes-but-no-answers?cb=1, so it seems likely the intent in these cases was to bump the question up to the front page. I think there is another discussion to be had about how the community feels about using edits to bump posts, but in either case edits should be complete.

Comment: @Tyberius there are other ways to bump the question, right? Like the community ♦ does sometimes?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer yes, but I believe the community bumps are generally automated and have a fairly specific time range over which they work. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: @Tyberius In that case, she should have stated "bump to homepage" in the edit description, or at least answered/commented here.

Comment: *"at least answered/commented here"* You have to be aware that people have their own lives to deal with, too, and I am sure she will reply when she has the time to. I know we're moderators and all that, but it doesn't mean we have to be always present...! On the issue of editing, I broadly agree with Tyberius' comment(s).

Comment: Also related: [Are questions being excessively edited?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4168/16683) where I've provided my stance on it - I shan't repeat it here.

Comment: @orthocresol Well I suppose that's true. That wasn't the main point, but the edit descroption was.

Comment: @Tyberius I can't agree with the reasoning that it posts *needed to be bumped* to the homepage. Reference: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/23837/revisions, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/107355/revisions. **I don't see why answers need to be bumped**.

Comment: @orthocresol I had gone through your answer before posting. Something still strikes me that it was not being implemented. I know it appears that I am making a fuss of things, but I am simply bringing up unusual behavior for discussion. You might see things differently.

Comment: Hey, I've been making a lot of edits to questions, but I have been visiting these questions for reasons other than editing. I've been looking for questions to compile in a list to retag, bounty, and especially questions that could use better answers. Usually, they are on the front page already and have had something removed (spammy answer.) Since the answer is usually removed, it appears that the bump to the front page has occurred because of the edit when that was not necessarily the cause.

Comment: Editing is really just a quick clean up I make after I exit the question having modded something or having visited it for other reasons. I have found in the past, from my own work, that long blocks of texts are hard/annoying to read and many of my edits have also included better formatting. I do agree that some of my edits have been trivial, but I do want to say that I try to edit what's on the front page and while the bump may appear to usually be due to the editing, there is often a mod that occurred and the question was already on the front page.

Comment: There have been a few questions, however, that weren't on the front page but those generally require more substantive edits. If I DO find a substantive edit anywhere in a question, I do often do even minor edits in its answers as the question will already end up bumped anyway.

Comment: I guess, to sum it up, if I'm on a question for any reason, I'll take a look at any formatting/grammar/spelling issues. If they are glaring, I'll definitely edit all q/a on the page. If there is any modding to be done, I'll definitely edit. If it's on the front page already, I'll definitely edit. I'll try to hold back on some of the editing in the future.

Comment: Some of the more superfluous edits do appear on this list. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/20-unanswered-questions-with-many-upvotes-but-no-answers

I'm looking back and forth at each of these questions, see if anyone's answered, and preen them as I add them to the list.

Comment: @MelanieShebel I appreciate your response. While there is no way I can know for sure, I'll take your word for it. But iirc, there weren't so many spammy answers. I'm(almost) always online. Well anyway, I could've missed something(*usually not, as I am fairly active on first post/late answers reviews*). I am glad that you are investing effort into the community, but I doubt whether excessive preening is necessary, especially considering most of the edits weren't *glaring*. Please do not stop working on the site- but yes, I still believe (for very logical reasons) that some restraint is great.

Comment: I fully acknowledge that the entire community may not side with my view. Anyway, @MelanieShebel, thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll still edit questions that I come across for other reasons, especially ones that hit the front page, but it's good to hear some feedback.

Comment: Also, I invite you to see my edited response to a similar question here: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3734/402

Comment: @MelanieShebel Yes I guess that makes some sense. Thanks for opening up a new perspective to which I was indifferent earlier. Would you like me to delete this thread? I am not expecting answers anyway.

Comment: Nah, you can keep it. It's a useful thread.