# Holiday Bounty Suggestions?

Tags: discussion, bounty

In the past, we've had some ["bounty dances."](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/lets-do-the-bounty-dance)

In the spirit of end-of-semester end-of-Gregorian-year Winter/Summer Bash spirit, I'd like to borrowing / shamelessly steal the previous idea, which seems to have fallen away over the last year or three. All credit to [Martin-マーチン](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4945/martin-%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%81%E3%83%B3).

### Let's get some [Bounties](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) rolling...

Bounties are a good way to draw attention to questions, draw traffic to the site, and reward newer users with internet points for good answers.

Sometimes, you come across a good question that did not get attention or answers. We have a [pile of unanswered, highly-voted questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/20-unanswered-questions-with-many-upvotes-but-no-answers-updated-18-oct-2022). Maybe you're interested in an answer, but don't want to give up 100 reputation.

I don't need or care to gain reputation points, so I'm happy to give them away.

### What are the rules for this?

It's quite simple. There are only a few rules.

#### Questions:

- A question that should be awarded a bounty to draw attention should be at least about a month old. (Preferably the asker is still active.)
- Should have a score of five or more, but <s>not more than 15</s>.
- Should not have an accepted answer. (In cases that the answer is outdated this point can be voided.)
- The last bounty on this question may not be younger than half a year.
- No [homework](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) questions.

#### Answers:

- An answer that is excellent (score > 15), but not the accepted answer, can get an additional bounty to mark it as great and/or reward the contributor.
- The question must be of our minimal quality standards, proper formatting, etc.
- The answer should not yet have a bounty awarded.
- The answerer must not be a 10k reputation user or yourself.

<sub><sup>Conditions are subject to change.</sup></sub>

### How to enter?

Post an answer here with the current title and link to the question and answer. Make sure the post follows the above guidelines. Please also state why the linked post should be bountied. Wait.
**You can enter as many questions as you find interesting.**

Comment: Oh that's a nice idea. Thank you for the initiative. I'm off course offering my services as a bounty donor. Have a very merry end of year y'all!

Answer (score 5):

This question remained unanswered for a long time, and now has a highly-rated and accepted answer:

[Single-molecule magnet with electrically-controlled permeability: How does the Titan Shield from Deus Ex work?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/78983/72973)

So it doesn't conform to the rules of this meta post, but I wanted to share nonetheless.