# No hats this year? Let's have some bounties instead!

Tags: discussion

There are some questions on this site that get a lot of views but don't have an answer. Some of them even have a high question score. Here are some examples (the two numbers behind the question are the score and the views as of Dec-22-2023):

1. [How to calculate transition dipole moment from two known wavefunctions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47529) 25  2357
2. [Do Cyclohexane-1,3-diones Give Positive Haloform Reactions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/135626)    22  3326
3. [Can we use phosphorus triiodide in Hell-Volhard-Zelinsky reaction?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38513)  18  1589
4. [Role of pH in azo C-coupling reaction, continued](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/112468)    11  1167
5. [Understanding two-electron integrals in Gaussian 09](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/100338)    11  1042
6. [At what temperature does charcoal burn?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59884)  10  12015
7. [Orbital and state correlation diagram for ring-closure of pentadienyl to a cyclic allyl](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47621)  10  1294
8. [Inter electronic repulsion in s and d orbitals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58423) 9   3480
9. [Why is the bond angle of N-N-N in hydrogen azide not 180 degrees?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/87465) 9   1854
10. [Why does the reaction of sodium nitrate, aluminium, and sodium hydroxide yield ammonia?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51666)  8   18766
11. [What are the limitations of the Born-Lande' equation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/133871)    8   3619
12. [Is hydronium an electrophile, nucleophile, both or neither?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/93809)  8   2828
13. [Tables/database/literature of specific or optical rotation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/41407) 8   2123
14. [What is the fabric in heating mantles made of?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/80611) 8   1495
15. [Why does reduction using sodium borohydride require a protic solvent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/100444) 8   1450

I selected these using a query ("answers:0 and score:2 and closed:false and views:1000") or [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/1811812), and picked the ones with the highest scores. Of course, that doesn't mean they are good questions, so check (and perhaps edit) before you place a bounty.

If you like one of them, though, you could put a bounty on it. If you don't want to spend your points, you can instead put a link of your favorite unanswered question in an answer to this post, and maybe someone else will sponsor a bounty (or answer it).

Of course, this is inspired by past [bounty dances](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3030) and [similar events](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5275).

Comment: @Karsten  Sadly, my entry (Q3) will never get an answer:(

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/dissociation-of-h3po4-and-colligative-properties

This question

Comment: What do the hats indicate?

Comment: @HarikrishnanM It has been put into bounty hat (bountied)

Comment: That means the bounty has been awarded?! OMG I answered it to get that!

Comment: @NilayGhosh I'll try. ;)

Comment: What about the gift box? Does it mean that the bounty has been awarded?

Comment: No, that means that one has an answer now (which I wrote without the question having a bounty).

Comment: I edited one question bountied by you - changed it from isobutyl chloride to *sec*-butyl chloride, since isobutyl chloride is primary and the OP had given it as secondary.

Comment: There's a set of rules by Martin: https://imgur.com/isYFIDb is it possible that these can be followed?

Comment: @NilayGhosh I wrote an answer to Q3. Not sure you like it, of course.

Comment: @Karsten I like it. Of course, I understand that not much research was done on this topic, so there is some room. I'll accept it although I will take a better look after the holidays. New year greetings in advance from my side.

Answer (score -2):

[Inductive effect on stability of free radical](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81343/inductive-effect-on-stability-of-free-radical)

This one also needs a bounty. I've explained it - but there's always someone who knows better than me.