# Placing bounties on old questions and getting them answers. Bounty Season?

Tags: discussion

We have a lot of questions that are good questions suited for this site. However, a lot of them do not have a proper answer/no answer. I would like to talk about requesting members in this community to put bounties on them if you don't think it has an answer (not as a comment) it should deserve.

If you have any questions on which question to put bounties on, please don't ask the question, since it should be on your willingness. Instead for a framework use this:

[20 most viewed questions that need answers (Updated April 16th 2021)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/20-most-viewed-questions-that-need-answers-updated-april-16th-2021?noredirect=1#comment10862_3458)

I shall be updating that list to the best of my abilities and a small 50 rep bounty is good enough unless you feel an deserves more.

I know Christmas is over (for those who celebrate it). But 'tis still the season of giving in this forum (Who needs a celebration for giving gifts to those who put in the effort?)

Thank you all for reading this small request and I hope to see more valid answers on this forum.

Comment: [Let's do the bounty dance](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/lets-do-the-bounty-dance/3180) :)

Comment: Good idea, I will see if I can put bounties on some questions.

Comment: @Nilay Yeah, someone remembered. (๑♡⌓♡๑)